# “There is a window in the wall.”vs.“There is a window on the wall.”?

Tags: prepositions

My question is which preposition should be use here. Besides, can I say “the wall with a window in it”? Or do you think “the wall with a window” is good enough?

Comment: Without any additional context, it will be hard to tell if _the wall with a window_ would be "good enough". Are we.... Telling the movers where to put the sofa? Telling an architect about our desired backyard view? Giving an artist advice on a painting? Helping a musuem curator ensure a painting doesn't get damaged from too much sunlight?

Comment: The window is "on the world"—not on the wall.

Comment: @Robusto A "window is on the world" implies a "window is **to** the world" in the context, I'd suppose, not a hole in the earth.

Comment: Why do you need a superfluous clause? “The wall with a window” works for me. OTOH, if all you wanted to know was what preposition to use, then it is *in,* not *on*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the window is not a surface detail, for semantic reasons I'd use

> 'There is a window in the wall'.

Compare

> 'There is a hole / door / gate in the wall.'

But

> 'There is a poster / balcony on the wall.'

Your second query really only concerns appropriate style, not grammar - both are fine.

Comment: “There is a window on the wall” is fine … if you're talking about a free-standing wall (like, say, the Berlin Wall or the Great Wall) on top of which has (for reasons unknown) been left an unfitted window lying or standing about. In any realistic scenario, though, it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I deeply appreciate your timely help. I've got what you taught. Thank you!